# Is the Wordpress /wp-admin folder generic?

Tags: php, wordpress

Can you replace the `/wp-admin` directory of a Wordpress installation with another one without issues?

This question is very open, but my current context is that I'm transferring a Wordpress site from one server to another. I've just come to download the site via FTP, and the `/wp-admin` folder has disappeared. (I probably did something wrong, but I did not knowingly delete the folder). I have a development version of the site, and am wondering if it will cause problems to just use the `/wp-admin` from that.

Has anyone come up against a similar thing before, and does anybody know if this folder is generic?

Comment: I have tried to upload the `/wp-admin` folder from my devlopment environment, and it seems to be working. I'm expecting a tonne of problems, but so far none. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to replace the folder with one of the same version. See http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Versions

There are, of course, updates and bug fixes along the way in many, but not all, versions, and a copy of `wp-admin` of a version not the same as the rest of the install will break things.

Check the file `version.php` in `wp-includes` to find the version of your WordPress install. ( `version.php` is not in `wp-admin`). And file modification dates are not a reliable way to check versions.)

See https://wordpress.org/download/release-archive/ for all versions.

Answer (score 1):

As long as no modifications to the core of WordPress have been done, you should be fine, but make sure that the wp-admin folder you're uploading belongs to the same WordPress version your website is running. You should face no issues at all.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, if you did have a Dreamweaver then try to search a word 'wp-admin' in Entire Website Folder in the search's Dreamweaver option.

Secondly, change all text that contain a word 'wp-admin'.

Third, change the folder's name.

Then test your wordpress, if there are errors so try to solve it or post a comment.